# Why does my selection gets only the last row?

Tags: 8, database

I rewrote for Drupal 8 a Drupal 6 query on 3 custom entities (see [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/205588/how-to-choose-between-classic-sql-query-and-drupal-8-technic)):

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$query = $database->select('amap_distributions_dates', 'amdd');
$query->leftJoin('amap_distributions_inscriptions', 'amdi', 'amdi.datedistributionid = amdd.id');
$query->leftJoin('association_personne', 'ap', 'ap.id = amdi.amapienid');
$query->fields('amdd', ['id', 'datedistribution', 'nombreproduits'])
    ->fields('amdi', ['id', 'datedistributionid', 'amapienid', 'role'])
    ->fields('ap', ['id', 'nom', 'prenom'])
    ->condition('nombreproduits', 0, '>')
    ->orderBy('datedistribution', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('role', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('nom', 'ASC')
    ->orderBy('prenom', 'ASC');
$results = $query->execute()->fetchAllAssoc('id');
foreach ($results as $row) { some code here }
```

Unfortunately, I can retrieve only the last of each {datedistribution-role-nom}.
For each 'datedistribution', if I have more than one 'role' or 'name', I can get only the last one considering the sort order I put in place.
Strange, no?
Any idea why?

Comment: Don't use fetchAllAssoc(). Just $result = $query->execute() and then loop over that.

Comment: You should consider loading the entire entity objects using entityQuery and loadMultiple.

Comment: @Berdir Do you know why I can't accept your comment as an 'answer' to my question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use fetchAllAssoc(). Just $result = $query->execute() and then loop over that